# Android Logcat: How do I output a log message with a TAB character?

Tags: java, android, tabs, logcat, ddms

In Java, `System.out.printf("\t")` gives a TAB character in the Console.

I wanted to have that function in the Logcat DDMS, by outputting a TAB character in my log message.

```
public void testLogMessage(){
    Log.d("Test", "TAB: " + "\t" + "AAAAAAAA" + "\t" + "AAAAAAAAA");
}
```

However, in the Logcat, I do not see the TAB character in the A's.

If possible, how should I output the TAB character in the Logcat? Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Probably I didn't make my question clear. I want to show up the TAB control character on this:

[image: Logcat]

I just could not get the TAB character to show up. Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you selected device in DDMS??

Comment: Yes I did. It has no effect whatsoever with any devices, virtual or hardware.

Comment: when u r calling testLogMessage function??

Comment: Whenever my Activity starts the `onResume()` method. I could see the A's very clearly, but no TAB character in between.

Comment: \t embedded in strings seems to work for me, verified the presence of a tab character in the output of logcat and even in eclipse.  I didn't need it, but you can try the binary flag, ie adb logcat -B

Comment: @ChrisStratton If possible, could you please post that as the answer to this question, so that I can vote you as answered and you get reps for it?

Comment: @ChrisStratton And another thing, I'm not familiar with the binary flag for Logcat. If you can explain it a bit more in your answer post, it will help out very much. Thanks!

Comment: Not being able to replicate the problem is more of a comment than an answer.  As for the binary flag (-B), see the logcat docs.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I have added some more info.

Comment: I have this problem too and I think logcat escapes tab and stuff...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If no one is able to prove that TAB characters can be outputted to Logcat, then I guess it means Logcat isn't able to display TAB characters.

I do not have a workaround for the TAB characters, nor do I wish to continue fixing this problem.